# What is the rank of symmetric Pascal matrix?

Tags: matrix-rank

Can two rows of a symmetric Pascal matrix (in general) be ever linear dependent?

Is the rank of a symmetric Pascal matrix always equal to the number of rows (m)?

I have a symmetric Pascal matrix where m=4 and n=4 and should count its rank.

Comment: A $4\times 4$ Symmetric Pascal Matrix has rank $4$. So, its rows are never linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks for an answer... is this generally valid for a symmetric Pascal matrix of any size?

Comment: Thats what I am thinking now ... Nice question.

Answer (score 1):

The symmetric pascal matrix $S$ has $LU$ factorization where $L$ is the lower triangular pascal matrix, and $U$ is the upper triangular matrix.  Both $L$ and $U$ have all ones on the diagonal.  In particular, the determinants of these are each 1.  Thus, using $\det(L)\det(U)=\det(LU)=\det(S)=1$ we can conclude that $S$ is invertible and must have rank=#-columns=#-rows.

In response to your question about dependence of rows:
It is equivalent to consider the columns (since it is symmetric).  By the above reasoning, no two rows/columns of $S$ can be linear combinations of each other.  In fact no $m$ rows or columns (where $1\leq m \leq n$=number of rows = number of columns) can be linearly dependent.